# Extract info from a binary file throught a template

Tags: java, templates, extract

I'm searching for a program that can extract information from binary files throught a template. For example if I have a xml file, and I want to extract some fields of it with the template. I already searched for this but i only get reverse program that is create a file throught a template, like Apache Velocity, FreeMaker, Hachoir. The program would be appreciate if it is in java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you only want to extract values from an XML file you could use `XPath` statements as templates. Sorry not a longer answer, as your question is to broad to understand what you want to achieve. Btw. what have you done so far?

Comment: I want to extract info from files with help of templates that you create for that specific type of file. I saw a lot of application but the reverse create the file with the template. To put it simple I want to read the file, but only some fields that are in the template.